# Where can I find a list of Indicators of Compromise (IOC) conditions?

Tags: tools, forensics, intrusion, threats, custom-scheme

OpenIOC.org has several schemas defining Indicators of Compromise.
The Schema is defined here:

```
http://schemas.mandiant.com/2010/ioc/ioc.xsd
```

While under `IndicatorItemContext/search` says it is `xs:string`, the actual list of search terms is listed here:

```
http://openioc.org/terms/Current.iocterms
```

Is there something similar for `IndicatorItem/condition`?
So far I'm only aware of `"contains"` and `"is"` but there doesn't seem to be a definitive list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unsure of where you can get a list from, but the [IOC Editor](https://www.fireeye.com/services/freeware/ioc-editor.html) may have visibly similar options. Meaning, you can browse the options to see what is available, and how it works. I'd also have a look at [IOC Finder](https://www.fireeye.com/services/freeware/ioc-finder.html) to see what options are available on that as well.

Comment: Hi, thanks the IOC editor has contains, is, contains not and is no, which I guess is definitive enough. I didn't think to use the IOCe!

Comment: "is no" in your comment should be "is not" - so the list of options would be: "contains", "is" "contains not" and "is not".  I'm just repeating this because without the quotes your comment is hard to read.